# Convert GeoJSON directly to geodatabase

Tags: geojson, convert, file-geodatabase

I'm looking for a way to convert a GeoJSON File (from overpass-turbo.eu) directly into a Feature Class in an Esri geodatabase.

Normally I'm doing this by loading the GeoJSON into QGIS, Export it to a shapefile and then import it into ArcGIS Pro. There I can just export the data into my geodatabase.  The problem is the limited space within the Attribute Table of shapefiles, which leads to a loss of data which I need in my current project.

Unfortunately I don't have access to the ArcGIS Data Interoperability Tool, so I have to find an open source way.

Comment: Have you tried the GeoJSON with the Esri supplied [JSON to Features](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/json-to-features.htm) tool

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to use ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -f "FileGDB" output.gdb input.geojson
```

Comment: https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/filegdb.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code

```
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/data"
arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion("myjsonfeatures.json", os.path.join("outgdb.gdb", "myfeatures"))
```

For more details please refer to [JSONToFeatures example](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/json-to-features.htm)

Comment: As explained in the help, if using `GeoJSON` as input, you need to supply the operational `geometry_type` parameter, specifying which type of geometry from the GeoJSON to convert. If you have multiple geometries inside the GeoJSON, you'll need to run the tool multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

The "JSON to Features" tool in ArcGIS Pro will allow you to output directly to a geodatabase.